# Can anyone explain the idea behind dS ∝ dV/V?

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, entropy

In a lecture on entropy, one of the equations $dS ∝ \frac {dV}{V}$ was explained as "a fractional change in volume as a measure of the increase in randomness" (related to $\frac{dQ}{T}$)

How does this concept of $\frac{dV}{V}$ work more precisely? What volume is $dV$ indicating exactly?

I'd be interested to read a paper/textbook notes on how this is conceptualised, since it seems relevant to molecular and structural biology (e.g. protein structural changes)

I understand entropy and am not asking about the meaning of the term, rather I am interested in this aspect of its derivation

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [first law of thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics),
$$dU=\delta Q-\delta W=TdS - pdV$$
then consider a reversible processes ($dU=0$), then we get
$$TdS=pdV$$
Then using the ideal gas law, $pV=nRT$, we find
$$
dS \sim \frac{dV}{V}
$$

The volume considered would be the volume of the system (e.g., a gas), with its infinitesimal increase(decrease) signified by $dV$.

Comment: Ah so the relationship only holds for gaseous processes?

Comment: AFAIK, it's applicable to any [thermodynamic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_system).

Comment: I understand that it pops out of the equations, I'm more interested in what this actually means - say for a biological thermodynamic system such as a protein. I've not come across changes in volume in this respect, and am wondering what it would refer to when there is said to be changes in entropy [since they are directly linked by the above relationship]

Comment: Looking at the equations, this holds if and only if pV = a constant.. it depends on the equation of state you use.. pv - a constant is true only for ideal gases.. please correct if the following is wrong.. for gases, an increase in volume suggests that there is more space for gas molecules to move around and hence it is more disordered and hence more entropy.. i am not sure whether u will be able to extend this idea to proteins, as there are much stronger intramolecular correlations exist in them which is absent in gases